# Monodroid ActionBar show menubutton on Galaxy

Tags: android, android-actionbar, xamarin.android

I need to show the menu button, in the ActionBar, even if it has a hardware key.

I found this in android:

```
try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Ignore
    }
```

But how to convert it to monodroid? I can't get the getDeclaredField method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ViewConfiguration.Get(Context).HasPermanentMenuKey
```

`HasPermanentMenuKey` is a `bool`, which you can use to find out whether the device has a permanent menu key. However you need to set minimum API level to 14 to have this working.

Comment: My target api is 14, but minimum is 7. But i need to set the menu-button.